# What is the simplest transaction framework in Java?

Tags: java, mongodb, transactions, jta

Given I have a simple task: process some piece of data and append it to the file. Its ok if I dont have exceptions, but this may happen. If something goes wrong I would like to remove all the changes from the file.

Also, may be I have set some variables during the processing and I would like to return their previous state too.

Also, may be I work with a database that doesn't support transactions (to the best of my knowledge MongoDB does not), so I would like to rollback it from DB somehow.

Yes, I can fix the issue with my file manually just by backuping the file and then replacing it. But generally looks like I need a transaction framework.

I dont want to use Spring monster for this. Its too much. And I dont have ELB container to manage EJB. I have a simple Java stand-alone application, but it needs transaction support.

Do I have some other options instead of plugging Spring or EJB?

Comment: You don't need transactions in case you are single threaded. Otherwise, you might simply want to lock the file using [java.nio.channels.FileLock](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/channels/FileLock.html).

Comment: You want database transactions, with databases that don't support them? And how is spring "too much" exactly ?

Comment: Markus, why? I just want to have a simple way to rollback my changes. It doesn't depend on the number of threads.

Comment: fabienbk, yes, with MongoDB, for example. Spring is a great framework but incorporating it all into small application is too much. I dont know wether I can pull out only a transaction support from it.

Comment: @Dymytry: I don't get your point. You do a calculation and want to append it to a file. This is either successful (in this case data is written), or not (in this case _no_ data is written). No need to roll back something in the latter case - _since no data is written_. In order to prevent concurrent threads to write to the file the same time, you impose a lock on the file just before flushing the data to it and remove that lock right after doing so. Clean, simple.

Comment: Markus its just a simple example, it can be more complicated. For example, we make a sorting of lines in a file which cannot be loaded into the memory because it is too big. We will change the data in that file by pieces. And if something went wrong we want to roll it back. Its a common question about transactions.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use spring, try to implements a simple Two-phase commit mechanism: [Two-Phase Commit Protocol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two-phase_commit_protocol)

Answer (score 0):

I am no Java expert but this sounds simple.

In fact I would not use transactions in an ACID compliant database since it doesn't sound like the right action.

Instead I would write to a temporary file, when your records have been written merge with the original file. That way if some records cannot be written to the file for whatever reason you just drop the old file and merging and saving the new file will be atomic within the program's memory and the OS's file system.

Comment: Merging is actually not too easy to do in a timely manner. Preparing the data in a buffer, locking the original file, flushing the buffer to that file and releasing the lock does the same and is thread safe.